# Date Difference in MySql via Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datediff

I'm a little lost on how I should do this any help or guidance would be appreciated. I have a table that has 3 columns with multiple values inserted into it basically a log_book table of events. We can say there is an order_id, event_status, and datetime. I need to get the difference of days between the datetime columns and sum them together where order_id=? and event_status=? I know how to limit my queries to get the data I want. But what would be the best way to get the difference in days and add them together. Essentially there could be only one entry with the same order_id and event_status or there could be multiple entries with the same order_id and event_status. 
**Event Status codes**

1 = initially assigned
2 = submitted for review
3 = sent back for more work
[image]

because 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-15 is 15 days
and 2015-01-17 to 2015-01-18 is 1 day
so the total days would be: 16 Days

Comment: `2015-01-18 - 2015-01-01` is 17 days..

Comment: it's 16 days becuase im only looking for the total days that the event_status was either 1 or 3. But there could be the same order_number with multiple 1's or 3's